# ionic1 popup doesn't work with bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, popup

I searched some answers but couldn't find exactly what I want.
i want to see at the I tag the little user icon left to the name text but it doesnt seen. Is it because of bootstrap or what do I wrong

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
  template: '<div class="form-group"> <label for="name" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Your name</label>'+
    '<div class="cols-sm-10"> <div class="input-group">'+
    '   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>'+
    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Enter your name.."/>'+
    '</div>     </div>  </div>'+



  ' <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">'+
  '<option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>',

  scope: $scope,
  buttons: [
    { text: 'Cancel' },
    {
      text: '<b>Save</b>',
      type: 'button-positive',
      onTap: function(e) {
        if (!$scope.data.wifi) {
          //don't allow the user to close unless he enters wifi password
          e.preventDefault();
        } else {
          return $scope.data.wifi;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

[Here is my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g01t.jpg)

Comment: Where exactly do you want the icon?

Comment: i took the code from here, this is what i want to do   http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/register-page

Comment: Have you referred FontAwesome CSS in your code? If not, please add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">` to `index.html`